# Re-directing to registration when adding products to cart

Tags: magento2

I want that when someone adds a product to the shopping cart, it is redirected to the registration page. In this way I can restrict the purchase only to registered users, how can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add checkout/cart/add pre-dispatch event and confirm if user is logged in or not and redirect to login page